# Kotlin class not found when built with jenkins

Tags: android, android-intent, jenkins, kotlin

locally on my machine my app built successfully & works fine when clicking to open an Kotlin Activity like:

```
galleryLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(PreferencesActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class)));
```

But after successfully built on Jenkins CI the click action will make app crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/noodoe/sunray/settings/preferences/gallery/GalleryActivity;
   at com.noodoe.sunray.settings.preferences.PreferencesActivity.lambda$setupListener$9(PreferencesActivity.java:248)
   at com.noodoe.sunray.settings.preferences.PreferencesActivity.access$lambda$9(PreferencesActivity.java)
   at com.noodoe.sunray.settings.preferences.PreferencesActivity$$Lambda$10.onClick(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.noodoe.sunray.settings.preferences.gallery.GalleryActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.noodoe.sunray.alpha-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.noodoe.sunray.alpha-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.noodoe.sunray.alpha-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
   at com.noodoe.sunray.settings.preferences.PreferencesActivity.lambda$setupListener$9(PreferencesActivity.java:248)
   at com.noodoe.sunray.settings.preferences.PreferencesActivity.access$lambda$9(PreferencesActivity.java)
   at com.noodoe.sunray.settings.preferences.PreferencesActivity$$Lambda$10.onClick(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

here's my [build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/cyberrob/c5a57c6c9b5b7a72baac709929e4b9ca), please help if you have any idea. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Run `gradle clean` and retry the build. Not sure about your Jenkins script and how your CI workflow runs, but a clean before the build is always recommended.

Why not post your Jenkinsfile / Jenkins CI script here =)